# In the proof of "maximal ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ are of the form $(p,f(x))$ "

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Maximal ideals of $R=\Bbb{Z}[x]$ are of the form $(p,f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ and $p$ is prime.

A quick search on google returns several proofs, which I cannot completely understand. Given a maximal ideal $M\subset {\Bbb Z}[x]$, a key step is to find the prime $p$ first. A(The?) way to do it is as the following. Let
$$
J=M\cap{\Bbb Z},
$$
which turns out to be an ideal in ${\Bbb Z}$ and hence has the form $J=(m)$ where $m$ is some integer. Suppose $m\not=0$ (showing that $J\not=(0)$ is a big part in the proof, which is not what I'm worrying about). My **question** is:

> how do I show that $m$ must be prime?

---

It suffices to show that there is an *injective* homomorphism $\phi:{Z}/(m)\to R/M$. But I don't see a clear way to find $\phi$. (It seems that it can be obtained from some induced homomorphism since $(m)\subset M$).

Comment: Comment about the statement (i.e. not about your question) : Having skimmed over several of these proofs (which compute the entire spectrum of $\mathbb Z[X]$) by googling myself, watch out ; most of them contain major mistakes. I was actually thinking of writing up a proof of my own since I haven't found a single flawless proof (although combining arguments from multiple wrong proofs gave me a correct proof...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\, m = ab\in M,\,\ a,b\not\in M\,$ then $M$ is not prime, so not maximal. Generally contractions of primes are prime. Further, in a UFD, prime ideals may be generated by primes (a property which characterizes UFDs).

Comment: I didn't noticed that this is immediately clear using prime ideals. I came up with this question when I read the Chapter 11 in Artin's Algebra. (The prime ideal is not defined until Chapter 13.)

Answer (score 5):

Here might be an alternative approach without using prime ideals explicitly.

Consider the inclusion homomorphism $i:\Bbb{Z}\to{\Bbb Z}[x]$ and the canonical homomorphism 
$\pi:{\Bbb Z}[x]\to\Bbb{Z}[x]/M$. It can be checked that the kernel of the homomorphism 
$$
\varphi=\pi\circ i:{\Bbb Z}\to{{\Bbb Z}[x]/M}
$$
is $M\cap {\Bbb Z}=J=(m)$. It follows that the induced homomorphism 
$$
\overline{\varphi}:{\Bbb Z}/(m)\to {\Bbb Z}[x]/M
$$ is injective. But ${\Bbb Z}[x]/M$ is a field. Hence ${\Bbb Z}/(m)$ must be an integral domain. Since it is also finite, it must be a field and hence $m$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the map $\varphi : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z[X]$ which maps integers to degree zero-degree polynomials (i.e. the canonical injection), then $M \cap \mathbb Z$ is precisely the pullback of the maximal ideal $M$ under this inclusion. Since $M$ is prime, $M \cap \mathbb Z$ is also prime ; since $\mathbb Z$ is a PID, $M \cap \mathbb Z$ is maximal.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Dear @Patrick, Just to be clear, you're using the non-trivial fact that $M\cap\mathbf{Z}$ is non-zero (I know the OP said he is taking that for granted but I just wanted to point it out for readers who might read your answer having missed that point from the OP).

Comment: @Kennan Kidwell : The OP assumed it ; he wrote $m \neq 0$. Of course I am using it! He wrote "Suppose m≠0 (showing that J≠(0) is a big part in the proof, which is not what I'm worrying about)"

Comment: Dear @Patrick, As I said in my comment, I was not suggesting that you weren't aware of it (and I noted that the OP mentioned he was assuming it). I was only mentioning it for readers that might come across your answer and not notice that the OP is taking that fact for granted.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell : Everything is okay then :)

Answer (score 2):

Recall the homomorphism theorem: if $A$ is a subring of $B$ and $M$ is an ideal of $B$, then we have an isomorphism
$$
\frac{A}{M\cap A}\to \frac{A+M}{M}
$$
because we have an obvious homomorphism $\varphi\colon A\to (A+M)/M$ given by $a\mapsto a+M$. The kernel of $\varphi$ is clearly $A\cap M$.

In your case, $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $M$ is maximal, so $(A+M)/M$ is a domain, being a subring of the field $B/M$. Therefore $A\cap M$ is prime.

Note that this doesn't use in any way the properties of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

More generally, if $f\colon A\to B$ is a ring homomorphism (the rings are commutative) and $M$ is a prime ideal of $B$, then $f^{-1}(M)$ is a prime ideal of $A$, for the same reasons: if $\pi\colon B\to B/M$ is the projection, then the kernel of $\pi\circ f\colon A\to B/M$ is precisely $f^{-1}(M)$, so we have an injective homomorphism
$$
\frac{A}{f^{-1}(M)}\to \frac{B}{M}
$$
which proves the claim, because $B/M$ is a domain.